# Uniquely identify objects in a scene using multiple calibrated cameras

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, camera-calibration, open3d

I have a setup with **multiple cameras** that all point towards the same scene. All cameras are **calibrated to the same world coordinate system** (i.e.: I know the location of all the cameras with respect to the origin of the world coordinate system).
In each image from the cameras, I will **detect objects in the scene** (segmentation). My goal is to count all objects in the scene and I do not want to count an object twice as it will appear in multiple images. This means that **if I detect an object in image A and I detect an object in image B, then I should be able to confirm that this is the same object or not.** It should be possible to do this using the 3D info I have due to my calibrated cameras. I was thinking of the following:

- Voxel carving. I create silhouettes out of all images with the detected objects. I apply voxel carving and then count the unique number of clustered voxels I have. this will be the number of unique objects in the scene?
- I also thought about for example taking the center of the object and then casting a ray from it into the 3D world, this for each camera and then detecting if the lines cross each other (from different cameras). But this would be very error-prone as the objects might have a slightly different size/shape in each image and the center might be off. Also, the locations of the cameras are not 100% exact, which will result in the ray being off.

What would be a good approach to tackle this issue?

Comment: That's an interesting challenge. I wish I knew more math to help, however hopefully I can help with a few ideas: 1. you should post a image/diagram of camera placement: would it be possible to take a photogrametric approach to compute depth maps/point clouds ? 2. Open3D implements [Voxel Carving](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/voxelization.html?highlight=carve#Voxel-carving) (though you might already know about it as your question hints): hopefully the cameras and objects placement doesn't result in occlusions that make the results unusable. ...

Comment: ...3. could you get away with having a 'floor' made of aruco markers which would give each camera some 3D information and it coulda also act as a low-resolution occupancy grid (as some objects will obscure aruco  markers on the floor). there will be a marker size trade-off between: large = easy for cameras to spot, but low-res in terms of occupancy, small = hard/error prone for cameras to spot, but higher res for occupancy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only know "object", but no categories or identities, and no other image information other than a bounding box or mask? Then it's impossible.

Consider a stark simplification because I don't feel like drawing viewing frustrums right now

[image: paintbrush.exe]

Black boxes are real objects. Left and bottom axis are projections of those. Dark gray boxes would also be valid hypotheses of boxes, given these projections.

You can't tell where the boxes really are.

If you had *something* to disambiguate different object detections, then yes, it would be possible.

One very fine-detail variant of that would be block matching to obtain disparity maps (stereo vision). That's a special case of "Structure from Motion".

If your "objects" have texture, and you are willing to calculate point clouds, then you can do it.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The objects are fruits, so they would all get the same class. So this would mean in fact, I only have the masks. 

Could you elaborate more on the point cloud approach, please? What kind of direction should I be looking to identify objects uniquely with the help of a point cloud?

Comment: keywords to search for: "structure from motion", "multiple-view geometry". given a point cloud and a mask from a single view, you can select points from the cloud that are "shadowed" by the mask.